# Write multiple line into external files

Tags: php

i have input like this:

```
<input type='hidden' name='col12[]'>
<input type='hidden' name='col13[]'>
<input type='hidden' name='col14[]'>
<input type='hidden' name='col15[]'>
```

i want to write multiple record from these fields into external file, i use php code to execute like this:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST["buttonSave"])) {
        $colFile = fopen("estimasi.txt", "w") or die();
        $colItems = $_POST['col12'];
        $colQty = $_POST['col13'];
        $colUnit = $_POST['col14'];
        $colPrice = $_POST['col15'];
        for($i=0;$i<sizeof($colPrice);$i++) {
            ?>
            <?php
            echo $colItems[$i];
            echo $colQty[$i];
            echo $colUnit[$i];
            echo $colPrice[$i];
            ?>
            <?php
        fwrite($colFile, $colItems[$i], $colQty[$i], $colUnit[$i], $colPrice[$i]);
        echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url='.dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']).'" />';
        }
    }
    ?>
```

but that is not working, is it wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP Write to file multiline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24478013/php-write-to-file-multiline)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code will work

```
fwrite($colFile, "\n", $colItems[$i], "\n", $colQty[$i], $colUnit[$i], $colPrice[$i]);
```

\n will write the next data in new line